# ggplot error bars are horizontal but should be vertical

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I created two plots with ggplot containing errorbars. My first plot shows the errorbars in the vertical direction like they should be but the second plot has them facing horizontally even though I used the same code. How can I change the direction of the error bars? They should both run vertically.

Plot 1:

```
head(arsum)
    ss   BV   N    a_rmse        sd          se          ci
1  300 .053 600 0.4490948 0.1939080 0.007916261 0.015547000
2  300 0.11 600 0.4326376 0.1876572 0.007661074 0.015045831
3  300 0.25 600 0.4028272 0.1758211 0.007177866 0.014096842
4  300 0.43 600 0.3736950 0.1587006 0.006478925 0.012724171
5  300 1.00 600 0.3328419 0.1163379 0.004749474 0.009327646
6 1000 .053 600 0.3211591 0.1379862 0.005633262 0.011063344

ggplot(data=arsum, aes(x=BV, y=a_rmse, color=ss, group=ss))+
   geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=a_rmse-se, ymax=a_rmse+se), width=.1)+
   geom_point()+
   geom_line()+
   geom_hline(yintercept=0)+
   ggtitle("Interaction Plot Single Level Discrimination")+
   xlab("ICC")+
   ylab("Discrimination RMSE")+
   labs(colour = "Sample Size")
```

Plot 2:

```
head(twsum)
   ICC items    N    w_rmse         sd           se           ci
1 0.05    10 2915 0.7025752 0.02322448 0.0004301566 0.0008434419
2 0.05    20 2905 0.6053087 0.02072466 0.0003845158 0.0007539515
3 0.05    50 2863 0.4738864 0.02033279 0.0003800024 0.0007451061
4 0.05    70 2849 0.4368722 0.02125809 0.0003982703 0.0007809273
5  0.1    10 2878 0.7155422 0.02341178 0.0004364043 0.0008556967
6  0.1    20 2907 0.6272082 0.02283895 0.0004235978 0.0008305823

ggplot(data=twsum, aes(x=ICC, y=w_rmse, color=items, group=items))+
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=w_rmse-se, ymax=w_rmse+se), width=.1)+
    geom_point()+
    geom_line()+
    geom_hline(yintercept=0)+
    ggtitle("Interaction Plot Single Level Within-cluster Theta RMSE")+
    xlab("ICC")+
    ylab("Within-cluster Theta RMSE")+
    labs(colour = "Number of \nItems")
```

Comment: it would be helpful to have some code to reproduce your data (or similar data)

Comment: The scales of the se's relative to the y-values are considerably different. I'm not sure your description of the resulting plots are correct. I do not see any "horizontal error bars". The `items` as groups are determining the connections of the "interaction plot".

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure I understand your comment. Both plots are line graphs with error bars for each point. The error bars should run vertically as they are the error around values based on the y-axis. For plot 1 the error bars run vertically but for plot 2 the error bars run horizontally. The x-axis is a factor variable so error bars running horizontally are meaningless. I can't understand why the error bars are different in the two plots. I would include the plots in my question but I do not have enough reputation points to include images in my posts.

Comment: The actual error bars are just too small to see because the SE are so small compared to the scale of the y variable.  The lines you see on the second plot are just the crossbars (top and bottom of the error bars) because `width = .1` is really big compared to the x axis scale.  Take a look at `width = .001` and things might start getting clearer.

Comment: Ah I see. Yes if I zoom in and make the width smaller I can see a small gap between the top and bottom of the error bars. Thanks for the clarification!